# How to create pull requests for stash from shell/commandline?

Tags: git, git-pull, bitbucket-server

I am running Atlassian stash and I can see the Pull request option on the Web based UI, but I want to know if my users can create Pull requests from their consoles for their working copies without using the stash web UI ?

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 Stash command line tools available:

https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/stash-command-line-tools

https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/org.swift.stash.cli

Note that a pull request requires commits in a branch to be pushed rather than using the local working copy, and this works well in practice.

Comment: thanks for correcting my Snafu with the 'working copy'/ branch. I get it now. I am just getting familiarized with GIT so thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have never done this, but it should be possible using the [Stash REST api](https://developer.atlassian.com/static/rest/stash/3.0.1/stash-rest.html) via some bash script or something to do the *POST*

> **/rest/api/1.0/projects/{projectKey}/repos/{repositorySlug}/pull-requests**
>   This API can also be invoked via a user-centric URL when addressing
>   repositories in personal projects. Create a new pull request between
>   two branches. The branches may be in the same repository, or different
>   ones. When using different repositories, they must still be in the
>   same {@link Repository#getHierarchyId() hierarchy}.
>
> The authenticated user must have REPO_READ permission for the "from"
>   and "to"repositories to call this resource.

It sounds like quite some work, considering you will need to authenticate and all that, but it might still be worth it for you